# datediff function in postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-function

i am new in **PostgreSQL** i try to create function

this is code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION diff(date Timestamp) RETURNS void
    As
    $$
    declare
    CURRENT_DATE Timestamp;
    number numeric;
    
    begin
            CURRENT_DATE=(SELECT CURRENT_DATE) ;
            
            number=(SELECT DATE_PART('day', 'date'::Timestamp - 'CURRENT_DATE'::Timestamp));
            
    end
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select  diff('2020-08-18');
```

when i select  diff it error = invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "date"

Comment: What is that function supposed to do? Especially because it doesn't actually return anything (`returns void`). Why not simply do `return "date" - current_date`?

Comment: it first time i create function  i try to create this function  i want to  pass date and function calculate  datediff  i have to change returns "date"-current_date ?

Comment: You don't need to write a function for that, you can simply subtract one date from the other, e.g. `current_date - date '2020-08-18'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write a wrapper around the `-` operator for dates that always subtracts the passed date from the current date, you will need to change your function to return a result, e.g. `returns integer`.

A PL/pgSQL function also needs a `return` statement to actually return a value.

`current_date` is a built-in function, you can not use it as a variable name - and the assignment of `current_date` to itself makes not sense to begin with. Just use `current_date` wherever you need it without (re)declaring it as a variable or assigning a value to it.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) subtracting a `date` value from another `date` value yields the difference in days. There is no need to use `date_part()` to get that (and you can't use `date_part()` on an integer to begin with).

You also don't need PL/pgSQL for wrapping a simple expression like that into a function:

Without knowing more details, it seems you are looking for this:

```
create function diff(p_input date)
  returns integer
as
$$
  select p_input - current_date;
$$
language sql;
```

The equivalent implementation in PL/pgSQL using an (not needed) intermediate variable to store the result would look like this:

```
create function diff(p_input date)
  returns integer
as
$$
declare
  l_result integer;
begin
  l_result := p_input - current_date;
  return l_result;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select diff(date '2020-08-18');
```